# Switch from Multitexture to GLSL BGE

Tags: game-engine

I would like to switch from Multitexture to GLSL mode in the Blender Game engine (unless shadows work in Multitexture), but I do not know the process. simply switching the button causes a full white screen. Help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press <kbd>N</kbd> to show the side panel an change from multi texture to gls.
[image]

If the image still white change the viewport shading shortcut <kbd>Z</kbd> to material or texture.

[image]

Comment: it render the objects, however all textures are solid white

Comment: when i turn on the matcap option I get a similar effect but in the 3d editor (solid mode)

Comment: you have to set gls as first img and material as second img. i tested with your blend and it works... what are you asking??

Comment: thx it works great